# ESLint Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

With this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { View, NavBar } from 'amazeui-touch';

import * as Pages from '../components';

const {  Home, ...Components } = Pages;
```

I get this eslint error:

```
7:16  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token .. Why?
```

Here is my eslint config:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    /* JSX */
    "react/prop-types": [1, {
      "ignore": ["className", "children", "location", "params", "location*"]
    }],
    "no-param-reassign": [0, {
      "props": false
    }],
    "prefer-rest-params": 1,
    "arrow-body-style": 0,
    "prefer-template": 0,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-bind": [0, {
      "ignoreRefs": false,
      "allowArrowFunctions": false,
      "allowBind": true
    }],
  }
}
```

....
....
What's the problem?

Comment: You need to use a parser that supports the object spread property proposal.

Comment: Wast the Unexpected Token "import"? That was my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337576/).

Answer (score 438):

Unexpected token errors in ESLint parsing occur due to incompatibility between your development environment and ESLint's current parsing capabilities with the ongoing changes with JavaScripts ES6~7.

Adding the "parserOptions" property to your .eslintrc is no longer enough for particular situations, such as using

```
static contextTypes = { ... } /* react */
```

in ES6 classes as ESLint is currently unable to parse it on its own. This particular situation will throw an error of:

```
error Parsing error: Unexpected token =
```

The solution is to have ESLint parsed by a compatible parser, i.e @babel/eslint-parser or babel-eslint for babel version below v7.

just add:

```
"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
```

to your `.eslintrc` file and run `npm install @babel/eslint-parser --save-dev` or `yarn add -D @babel/eslint-parser`. If you use `pnpm`, you can instead run `pnpm add -D @babel/eslint-parser`.

Please note that as the **new Context API** starting from `React ^16.3` has some important changes, please refer to the [official guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype).

Comment: `yarn add -D babel-eslint` for those using Yarn.

Comment: For those who don't know where to add the `"parser": "babel-eslint"` config statement, it's in the `.eslintrc.json`. In my case, it's a JSON file, but basically, your .eslintrc file

Comment: Note * If you have "ejected" your create-react-app and you are adding eslint-ing to your IDE, babel-eslint is already applied. Just add the parser and your good to go.

Comment: I found this article helpful too: https://grantnorwood.com/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token-visual-studio-code/

Comment: I added the `"parser": "babel-eslint"` to my eslintrc file but got multiple errors instead. I am working with react and it tells me that My imported components were called but never used. Which is wierd.

Comment: If using "parser": "babel-eslint", then showing other error like { } for destructing.

Comment: Pankaj - restructuring requires a babel plugin - such as `@babel/preset-env`.

Comment: Even after adding this, a pre-requisite is that node version should be 8 or above.

Comment: `babel-eslint` is outdated, use `@babel/eslint-parser`

Comment: solution works with NestJS too, just remove the quotes from "parser" and add it to your .eslintrc.js and then install babel. - instead "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser" do parser: "@babel/eslint-parser".

Comment: add `parser` where in the eslintrc file?

Answer (score 118):

In my case (im using Firebase Cloud Functions) i opened `.eslintrc.json` and changed:

```
"parserOptions": {
  // Required for certain syntax usages
  "ecmaVersion": 2017
},
```

to:

```
"parserOptions": {
  // Required for certain syntax usages
  "ecmaVersion": 2020
},
```

Comment: Changing `emcaVersion` to `2020` did the trick for me when receiving this error for using `var?.prop` in a React app. Thank you for posting.

Comment: changing `ecmaVersion: 2017` to `ecmaVersion: 2020` returned an error: `error  Parsing error: Invalid ecmaVersion`. What else should I do besides changing to 2020?

Comment: Instead of changing `ecmaVersion: 2017` to `ecmaVersion: 2020` I just changed `"scripts": { "lint": "eslint ." }` to `"scripts": { "lint": "eslint" }` in the file **package.json** .

Comment: @AlitonOliveira I think that just disables eslint entirely

Answer (score 93):

`"parser": "babel-eslint"` helped me to fix the issue

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "modules": true,
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
    "rules": {
        "comma-dangle": 0,
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
        "react/display-name": 1,
        "no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "no-console": 1,
        "no-unexpected-multiline": "warn"
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "pragma": "React",
            "version": "15.6.1"
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/gildata/Roles/issues/6)

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to @JaysQubeXon's answer.

Comment: Actually it does - you get an example config (with parserOptions included)

Comment: Great to have the full example++. It helped me to fix a TamperMonkey JS hints error.

Comment: @brasofilo where do you change eslint in tamper monkey?

Comment: @Metin, go to `Dashboard > Settings > Editor > Custom Linter Config`

Comment: Fixed for me! Hurrah! Thanks.

Comment: This example worked for me, because of `"parser": "babel-eslint"` instead of `@babel/eslint-parser`, even though I am on latest yarn and install with  `yarn add -D @babel/eslint-parser`, so that did not work, but without the `@babel/` it worked.

Answer (score 85):

ESLint 2.x experimentally supports ObjectRestSpread syntax, you can enable it by adding the following to your `.eslintrc`: [docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options)

```
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
  }
},
```

ESLint 1.x doesn't natively support the spread operator, one way to get around this is using the [babel-eslint parser](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint). The latest installation and usage instructions are on the project readme.

Comment: That's not true. ESLint's default parser Espree does support spread, and even object rest spread (that's the only experimental feature that espree supports). For more information see this: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options

Comment: You're right, my original answer only applied to ESLint 1.x, I updated it with info for 2.x

Comment: `ecmaFeatures` has been deprecated. Use `ecmaVersion`

Comment: `ecmaVersion: 2018` works without a warning with ESLint 5

Comment: I don't see a problem with this solution - it worked fine for me. It's better than having to install a new package as well!

Comment: I am facing same issue with js  project. Above solution didn't work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 37):

I solved this issue by 
First, installing babel-eslint using npm

```
npm install babel-eslint --save-dev
```

Secondly, add this configuration in .eslintrc file

```
{
   "parser":"babel-eslint"
}
```

Comment:  However [babel-eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint) is no longer supported. Use its successor, [@babel/eslint-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/eslint-parser). `npm i -D @babel/core @babel/eslint-parser` then `{"parser: "@babel/eslint-parser"}`

Answer (score 16):

Originally, the solution was to provide the following config as object destructuring used to be an experimental feature and not supported by default:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  }
}
```

Since version 5, this [option has been deprecated](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-5.0.0#experimental-object-rest-spread).

Now it is enough just to declare a version of ES, which is new enough:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm using `eslint` for cloud-functions (development env: flutter 2.2.3).

In my case `.eslintrc.json` does not exist so I had to update the `.eslintrc.js` file by including `parserOptions: { "ecmaVersion": 2020, },` property at the end of file. My updated `.eslintrc.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
  
  // Newly added property
  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
  },
};
```

Comment: Works perfect. [Also check browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem by setting this in *.eslintrc.json* file:

```
"extends": [
    ...,
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
]
```

Answer (score 10):

Just for the record, if you are using **eslint-plugin-vue**, the correct place to add `'parser': 'babel-eslint'` is inside `parserOptions` param.

```
  'parserOptions': {
    'parser': 'babel-eslint',
    'ecmaVersion': 2018,
    'sourceType': 'module'
  }
```

https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#faq

Answer (score 8):

### In febrary 2021 you can use theese values

ecmaVersion - set to 3, 5 (default), 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, or 12 to specify the version of ECMAScript syntax you want to use. You can also set to 2015 (same as 6), 2016 (same as 7), 2017 (same as 8), 2018 (same as 9), 2019 (same as 10), 2020 (same as 11), or 2021 (same as 12) to use the year-based naming.

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options

Answer (score 7):

In my case adding `"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",` line into my .eslintrc file helped:

```
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": ["tsconfig.json"],
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
```

package.json in the same time has these 2 lines:

```
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
```

Answer (score 5):

For **React + Firebase Functions**

**Go to :** functions -> .eslintrc.js

**Add it -**
parserOptions: {
ecmaVersion: 8,
},

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 8,
  },
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "google"],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

Comment: Mine was on version 11... all of 10 and below worked but not 11

Answer (score 1):

If you have got a pre-commit task with husky running `eslint`, please continue reading. I tried most of the answers about `parserOptions` and `parser` values where my actual issue was about the node version I was using.

My current node version was 12.0.0, but husky was using my nvm default version somehow (even though I didn't have `nvm` in my system). This seems to be an [issue with husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/77) itself. So:

1. I **deleted `$HOME/.nvm` folder** which was not deleted when I removed `nvm` earlier.
2. Verified node is the latest and did proper parser options.
3. It started working!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using typescript and I solve this error change `parser`

```json
....
"prettier/prettier": [
            "error",
            {
                .....
                "parser": "typescript",
                .....
            }
        ],
....
```

Comment: I'm unclear on where you're suggesting to make these changes. I'd appreciate you taking a look at my ESLint question here since you may be able to answer. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/q/67522592/470749

Comment: You must make these changes to the prettier / prettier rule in your eslint file

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the issue despite implementing all the above solutions. When I downgraded the eslint version, it started working

Comment: Your answer could have been helpful if you specified what version wasn't working and then what version you downgraded to in order to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

```
.
.
{
    "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
},
.
.
```

Will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update the `ecmaVersion` to `"latest"`

```
"parserOptions": {
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    },
    "requireConfigFile": false
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a similar error, deleting your `yarn.lock` file (or `package.lock` if you're not using yarn) and then running `yarn install` (or `npm install`) again may fix it.