# eslint error when I set the state in react

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have really simple exaple in react

```
export default class App extends Component{
  state={
    count:0
  }
```

I have a ESLint error under state={....:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token = eslint

I don't know why... do I have  to install ESLint-react plugin?

this my eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true
  },
  extends: [
    'standard'
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    'react'
  ],
  rules: {
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using babel to transpile your code? If yes then you need `babel-eslint`.

Comment: I had create a react-app with npx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ESLint Parsing error: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001552/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token)

Comment: thanks solved it with babel-eslint