# error eslint parsing: unexpected token eslint error

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, eslint, ecmascript-2016

i am getting unexpected token on the square bracket.

i have tried setting the eslint parameters and install babel-eslint but nothing works for me.

```js
const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(createUserReducer, 
  {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    verifyPassword: ''
   });


my eslint configuration: 

{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "blockBindings": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "extends": "rallycoding",
  "rules": {
    "react/require-extension": "off",
    "global-require": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "unexpected-token": 0
  }
}
```

I should be able to build the code but eslint is throwing error saying unexpected token.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that supporting `JSX` syntax is not the same as supporting `React`. `React` applies specific semantics to `JSX` syntax that ESLint doesn’t recognize. We recommend using `eslint-plugin-react` if you are using `React` and want `React` semantics. By the same token, supporting ES6 syntax is not the same as supporting new `ES6` globals (e.g., new types such as Set). For `ES6` syntax, use { `"parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 6 } }`; for new `ES6` global variables, use `{ "env": { "es6": true } }`.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the code in the question, which doesn't use jsx at all?

Comment: @Bergi The questioner wants to use parameters globally. But like my answer, React does not automatically activate the entire ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Try these configurations :

> eslintrc.js :

```
module.exports = {
      root: true,
      "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    };
```

> eslintrc.json :

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "google"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this? Which of the changes solves the OPs problem, and how?

Comment: take a look:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001552/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token