# Parsing error: The keyword 'class' is reserved

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, brackets

I have a class object that I thought was working last night. But now I try to test out my set Hash method so I do: blah = new HashTable; and it says that HashTable isn't defined.

I have another file thats not linked here and all its variables are also showing up as undefined(in the console). I swear I got this working last night though so i'm miffed.

I'm getting an error that maybe I didn't notice before but it says

**ERROR**: Parsing error: The keyword **'class' is reserved** class HashTable

**JSLint(2)**
Expected an **identifier** and **instead saw 'class'**.
Stopping. (4% scanned).

What am I doing wrong? Someone please help.

My desire, is just to be able to test out my javascript code in the console to make sure that everything is working. I tried google chrome's snippet and it has bugs. I tried codepen and it's a sandbox so it doesn't work properly in the console now I'm trying brackets and it's not letting me test in the console either. Getting so frustrated.

```
class HashTable {
    constructor(size){
        this.keyMap = new Array(size);
    }

function _hash(key) {
    let total = 0;
    let prime = 31
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(key.length, 100); i++) {
        let char = key[i];
        let value = char.charCodeAt(0) - 96;
        total  = (total * prime + value) % this.keyMap;
    }
    return total;
   }

    function set(key){
        hashNumber = this._hash(key);
        return hashNumber;
    }

}
```

-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src = "app.js"></script>
    <script src = "hash.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please work</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whatever tool is giving you the error on `class` is out of date. As of ES2015, `class` isn't just reserved, it's in use -- for what you're trying to use it for. Sounds like you need to update your tools, I'm sure the current version of JSLint (for instance) understands `class` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it specifically relates to the errors you've called out or not, but your `HashTable` class has syntax errors in it. You don't use `function` to define the methods of a class within a `class` construct. So:

```
class HashTable {
    constructor(size){
        this.keyMap = new Array(size);
    }

    _hash(key) {
//  ^--------------------------------------- no `function` here
        let total = 0;
        let prime = 31
        for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(key.length, 100); i++) {
            let char = key[i];
            let value = char.charCodeAt(0) - 96;
            total  = (total * prime + value) % this.keyMap;
        }
        return total;
    }

    set(key) {
//  ^--------------------------------------- nor here
        hashNumber = this._hash(key);
        return hashNumber;
    }
}
```

---

Other notes:

- There's almost never any reason to use `new Array`.
- You're using the array you've assigned to `this.keyMap` as a number in the expression `total  = (total * prime + value) % this.keyMap;` which doesn't make any sense.
- I'd recommend calculating the upper bound of your `for` loop **once**, and then reusing that value, rather than calculating it on every loop iteration.

Comment: Yes that fixed it completely. Thank you! I was dying. I'm still getting the error but at least its working now and that's all I care about. I also had variables declared in my other js file and I removed the var declaration and they started working as well. Your the best!

Comment: oh I was using prime numbers because I heard theirs some math that makes the hash function give numbers more spread out and also makes the calculation faster.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly true @T.J. Crowder: `ESLint 7.11.0` with `node 14.14` (currently the latest versions) will throw this error.

Even though `ESLint` is favored over `JSLint` (as mentioned [here](https://www.slant.co/versus/8626/8628/%7Ejslint_vs_eslint)), it seems `babel-eslint` is preferred (as is mentioned with the how to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001552/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token)) and it will solve this problem.