# Parsing error: Unexpected token/Expression expected.ts(1109)

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex, eslint, vuex-modules

I am trying to modularise my Vuex store by writing below code

```
import state from './state'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'
import * as actions from './actions'

export const recoSideB = {
  namespaced: true,
  state = { ... } ,
  mutations= {... },
  actions= { ... },
  getters= { ... }
}
```

but getting Expression Expected.ts(1109)
 I have tried below config changes in eslint

```
parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    ecmaFeatures: {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
```

as per the answer by 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36003974/7596740

but still facing the parsing issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error occuried, because your object is incorrect.

Your object is:

```
export const recoSideB = {
  namespaced: true,
  state = { ... } ,
  mutations= {... },
  actions= { ... },
  getters= { ... }
}
```

But correct version must be:

```
export const recoSideB = {
  namespaced: true,
  state :{ ... } ,
  mutations:{... },
  actions:{ ... },
  getters:{ ... }
}
```