# ESlint Parsing error: Unexpected token => when deploying firebase functions

Tags: firebase, parsing, google-cloud-firestore, eslint

Code:

```
exports.detectEvilUsers = functions.firestore
    .document('messages/{msgId}')
    .onCreate(async (doc, ctx) => {
// code 
});
```

When I try "firebase deploy --only functions", the message ESlint Parsing error: Unexpected token => appears

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "firebase project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "firebase": "^8.2.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^2.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.13",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0"
  }
}
```

My .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
};
```

and my package.json inside /functions:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.13",
    "bad-words": "^3.0.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And the .eslintrc.js inside /functions:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

I installed babel, tried several configs. Nothing works so far. I do not know what to do.

Comment: Does any of the recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001552/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token) help?

Comment: hi, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I found this here: https://javascript.tutorialink.com/parsing-error-unexpected-token-when-trying-to-deploy-firebase-cloud-function-i-couldnt-find-any-answers-on-here/

It isn't choking on the arrow function per se, but rather the **async** arrow function.

For some reason eslint as installed by the firebase cli defaults to `es6: true` in `firebase/.eslintrc.js`. I'm surprised as async arrow functions are pretty common in 2022. Try changing that to something like:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es2017: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "max-len": "off",
    "semi": ["error", "never"],
  },
}
```

I don't know if es2017 is the best version to use in 2022, so someone please inform me what is currently standard.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// I think you have forgot to add closing } 
// this is the right way to create a trigger if there is still an error then that error would not be a trigger error
exports.myTrigger = functions.firestore
  .document('collection-name/{id}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => { 
  
       const id = context.params.id;
       const data = snap.data();
  
  })
```