# Firebase Deploy Error while deploying functions

Tags: node.js, npm, firebase-realtime-database, lint

I`ve installed:

npm 8.1.4

node 16.13.0

I'm trying to deploy some functions to the Firebase database for a Unity project, but an error returns when executing the firebase deploy command:

```
C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\CloudFunction\FirebaseFunctions\functions>firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'xxx'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\CloudFunction\FirebaseFunctions\functions\index.js
  47:95  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

As lint is new to me, what does the following error mean and how to resolve:

`Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT`

The error is also pointing at this UploadAndCompressVideo function in the index.js:

```
exports.UploadAndCompressVideo = functions.runWith(vdeioUploadOpts).https.onCall(async (data) => {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll refer to:

[ESLint Parsing error: Unexpected token:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001552/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token)

And the comment in one of the answers that did it for me:

> Instead of changing ecmaVersion: 2017 to ecmaVersion: 2020 I just changed "scripts": { "lint": "eslint ." } to "scripts": { "lint": "eslint" } in the file package.json . –
> Aliton Oliveira
> Apr 29 at 1:03