# how can i fix Unexpected token error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to write a transcription script in nodejs to deployed to google cloud function. here is the code

I am using node v17.5.0

```
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
const transcription = response.results
```

but I keep getting this error

> 160:30  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token client

I have made multiple attempts including modifying .eslinrc.js file and still can't solve the problem.

what is causing this and how can i fix it?

Comment: What version of Node is involved?

Comment: @Pointy node v17.5.0

Comment: Did you try any of these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001552/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token

Comment: @GrafiCode that question is  fairly old; Node 17 definitely supports `async/await`.

Comment: @Pointy I don't know why you mention async/await, it is a fairly old question but it is about eslint and babel

Comment: @GrafiCode ah, OK I didn't pick up on the fact that it's a lint problem and not a Node error.

Comment: This error log is mostly caused by the ‘eslintrc’ file as you have already mentioned and discussed in stackoverflow.com/questions/ 53735009, 36001552, 67770785, 56035645, 48408143, 66416001, 66500682. But the error is also pointing at your “client” variable that is related to the [speech to text](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/speech/latest/speech/v1.speechclient-class#_google_cloud_speech_v1_SpeechClient_recognize_member_1_) library. More details as your complete file or code would be very appreciated to provide more help as well as what you have tried so far.