# How to get documents from cloud firestore in cloud function with Java Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I wrote test cloud function that will trigger at adding new like to post in my Cloud Firestore database. In body of the function then I want to get user tokens in order to send notification to him(have not implemented it yet).
When I am trying to deploy this cloud function to firebase, I get this error: "error  Parsing error: Unexpected token tokensRef". What can be wrong?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.showNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/likes/{joinedId}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const userId = context.params.userId;
      const tokensRef = db.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("tokens");
      const snapshot = await tokensRef.get();
      
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data())
      })
    });
```

ESlint config:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

Comment: Do you have ESLint configured? If yes, can you update your question with it's config?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the function as `async`, since you use `await`. Also, you need to return a Promise or a value when all the asynchronous work is complete (more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) in the doc).

```
exports.showNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/likes/{joinedId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {  // <== See async here
      const userId = context.params.userId;
      const tokensRef = db.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("tokens");
      const snapshot = await tokensRef.get();
      
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data())
      })

      return null;
    });
```

Comment: now I get error "error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>"

Comment: Do these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001552/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token) help you?