# How to have reusable selectors with Cypress pageObject class?

Tags: javascript, cypress, eslint, private-members

I'm trying to use a pageObject in Cypress, I want to have my selectors in the same file so I can reuse them in multiple functions and only need to change them in one place if they need updating.

Here is a simple example:

```
class HomePage {
  searchLink = "a[class='search button']";

  clickSearchLink() {
    cy.get(this.searchLink).click();
  }
}

export const homePage = new HomePage();
```

This works fine, my test can call the functions e.g. homePage.clickSearchLink() but I have two issues:

1. When I run eslint it fails with

> e2e/page-objects/home-page.js   2:14  error  Parsing error: Unexpected
> token =

2. Doing it this way means searchLink is available in my spec files, I want it to only be seen in this class. I tried setting searchLink to a let or var but that just made it unusable in the clickSearchLink() function.

Is it possible to have my selectors in this class and still pass linting?

Comment: You can look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43426331/4571271

Answer (score 1):

If you bump the Typescript target to es6/es2015 you can use private fields.

[Private Class Features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

> #### Private class features
>
> Class fields are public by default, but private class members can be created by using a hash # prefix. The privacy encapsulation of these class features is enforced by JavaScript itself.

For the ESLint error, add a constructor.

```js
class HomePage {
  #searchLink: string;
  
  constructor() {
    this.#searchLink = "a[class='search button']";
  }

  clickSearchLink() {
    cy.get(this.#searchLink).click();
  }
}

export const homePage = new HomePage();
```

**/cypress/tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    ...
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```